# GWT DataGrid header click event for sorting

Tags: gwt

I want to know if user clicked on header for Ascending or Descending sorting.
How can I find that?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) create SortHandler and attach to your grid

```
ColumnSortEvent.AsyncHandler sortHandler= new ColumnSortEvent.AsyncHandler(grid);
grid.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
ColumnSortList columnSortList = grid.getColumnSortList();
```

2) create your Column (TextColumn etc) such as:

```
TextColumn<Dog> yourTextColumn = new TextColumn<Dog>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(String object) {
       return object;  
    }
}
```

3) create your Header

```
Header yourHeader = new Header() {
   @Override
   public Object getValue() {
       return value; // here return header value
   }
}
```

3) add column to grid and push a ColumnSortInfo onto the list

```
grid.addColumn(yourTextColumn, yourHeader);
columnSortList.push(new ColumnSortList.ColumnSortInfo(yourColumn, true));
```

You can always look [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) for more useful examples.

Comment: question is not how to Sort,, it is how to know if header is clicked!!

Comment: As Onkar mentioned, i want to know was header clicked for Ascending or Descending.

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the direction of the ordering, all you have to do is to get the ColumnSortList and call method #get(0) with zero index. as documentation of ColumnSortList says the "The 0th item is the {@link ColumnSortInfo} of the most recently sorted * column.". so the returned object (which is ColumnSortList.ColumnSortInfo) contains information about last clicked Column and it has a method called #isAscending() which is a flag to identify the direction.

the sample code:

```
ColumnSortList sortList = dataGrid.getColumnSortList();
ColumnSortList.ColumnSortInfo info = sortList.get(0);
```

also want to note that this code block should be in AsyncDataProvider#onRangeChanged.

there is also an alternative to this, consider the following:

```
            columnSortHandler = new ColumnSortEvent.AsyncHandler(table) {
            @Override
            public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) {
                List<T> newData = new ArrayList(table.getVisibleItems());
                if (event.isSortAscending()) {
                    Collections.sort(newData, (Comparator)event.getColumn());
                } else {
                    Collections.sort(newData, (Comparator)event.getColumn());
                    Collections.reverse(newData);
                }
                table.setRowData(newData);
            }
        };
        table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```